# Postgres: Move records from a local database to a remote database

Tags: postgresql

**Background Info**

I am writing an application written in ASP.NET Core 2.1.0 with PostgreSQL as its backend database. I'm using EF Core as an ORM.

The application has authentication/authorization needs, so on the startup of my application, **I am seeding the database with an Admin user account**. Locally all is working fine.

I now wish to deploy the application to the server. I've deployed the code, and I've used EF Core's migration commands to get a script for creating the tables on the remote database. That too has gone well.

*Now the issue is the seed data*. I do not know what the best way if of moving that seed data out to the production database.

**What have I done so far?**

Through pgAdmin, I created a plain backup of the records in the database. Here is a [screencast of exactly how](https://www.screencast.com/t/22zDvvpJ4X) I did that, I am not certain if that is the right way, but the generated script "looks fine".

I then logged into my production server via SSH, and switched user to the postgres user, and ran the following command:

```
psql -f phoneden-data.sql "Phoneden-Db-C3del"
```

That seemed to work, I ran the below select statement, and and I can see my records:

```
SELECT * FROM "AspNetUsers";
```

My records are in, but when I try to log in with the admin user, I cannot, it says it can't verify my login details.

So something is off with the way I've moved data from my local Db to the production Db.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the user rows are the same as the ones in your development database, then there might be a problem with your app. There are multiple things that you should check. Is your app able to connect to the database, are you using the same hashing algorithm for the passwords and etc.
You need to debug the application and find why is that error message shown, so we can help you solve it.

Comment: Does your server have a master secret (salt) or something?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a permissions issue. The owner of the Postgres database had 0 privileges, after granting the various privileges required, all started working.